# Limit $a_n = \frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n+1)!}}, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: limits

How do I show that the result is zero?

$\lim(a_n)= \frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n+1)!}}, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}$

$\frac{(n+1)!}{\sqrt{(2(n+1)+1)!}}/
\frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n+1)!}}
$

$\frac{(n+1)}{\sqrt{(2n+3)!}}*
{\sqrt{(2n+1)!}}
$

I will use the ratio test, but in the calculations I will get to the result 1/2 which is quite wrong, see the previous procedure.

Comment: The result of *what* is zero?

Comment: @Bernard There is the `limits` tag.

Comment: That doesn't tell what exactly the question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $\binom{2n}{n} \ge 1$ we obtain $\sqrt{(2n)!} \ge n!,$ hence $\frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n+1)!}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}} \to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Split it up into:

(n / sqrt ((2n + 1) (2n))) * ((n-1) / sqrt ((2n-2)(2n-3)) * ((n-2) / sqrt((2n-4)(2n-5)) ...

Each factor is slightly smaller than 1/2, so the total is slightly smaller than (1/2)^n.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n = \frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n+1)!}}\implies \log(a_n)=\log(n!)-\frac 12 \log((2n+1)!)$$

Use Stirling approximation twice and continue with Taylor series
$$\log(a_n)=-n \log (2)+\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\frac{\pi }{4 n}\right)-\frac{3}{16
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$a_n= e^{\log(a_n)}\sim 2^{-n}\,\frac{\sqrt[4]{\pi } }{\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{n }}\exp\left(-\frac{3}{16 n} \right)$$